# Pass the pipe character from a DOS batch script in a CALL statement

Tags: batch-file, dos, call, pipe

within a DOS batch script (that needs to run in the Win 200x and Win7 environments) I need to pass a particular character, in quotes, to another executable; e.g.

```
 doparse -delimeter "$"
```

In general this works:

```
 CALL CMD /C "doparse -delimeter "$""
```

Unfortunately, I need to specify the pipe character as the delimeter (this is a requirement). I expected the following would work:

```
 CALL CMD /C "doparse -delimeter "^|""
```

But when I run the script I don't see any output at all for this line (e.g. no error message if I replace "doparse" with some non-existent name).

I've tried various combinations of escape chars but cannot get it to work. Is it possible? (Has to be done via a batch script, unfortunately).

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `CMD /C`? It was only required in old versions of DOS that didn't support the CALL syntax to invoke one batch file from another. Also it isn't necessary to quote the parameters to `CMD /C`, you're thinking of `sh -c` which does take one quoted parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
call delim -delimiter "|"
```

and then using it like this in the called batch:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "delim=%~2"
echo Delimiter: !delim!
```

Comment: That's it. Somehow I missed the simpler CALL syntax. Thanks Joey!

Comment: The solution is simple, but the cause of the failure is complex ;-)

Answer (score 1):

These versions should work `cmd /c "test2.bat "^|""` and `cmd /c ^"test2.bat "|""`.
Both starts the test2.bat.

Also the version of Joey works.

The problem in your case is the `call` and the number of quotes, it's not possible to escape special characters in a `call` statement (outside of quotes), at least without the special caret trick.

Example

```
set "caret=^"
call echo &
call echo ^&
call echo ^^&
call echo ^^^&
call echo "&"
call echo %%caret%%^&
```

Only the last two works, the first is inside of quotes and the second escapes the `&` in the second parser run with the special caret trick.

In your case the `|` is outside of the quotes (it's after the second quote).
And there is a bug in cmd.exe so it immediatly stops, if the parser founds a unescaped `&` or `|<>` after a call phase.